# I am getting this error: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, pandas

How can I resolve this error that I am receiving:

```
 I/O operation on closed file.
```

This is my code:

```
def read_in_csv(csv_file):

    with open(csv_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:

        reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',',

                            quotechar='"')

    data_read = [row for row in reader]

    return data_read




def get_data(filename):

    data = read_in_csv(filename)

    data_dict = {}

    for row in data[1:]:

        category = row[0]

        text = row[1]

        if (category not in data_dict.keys()):

            data_dict[category] = []

        data_dict[category].append(text)

    return data_dict
```

```
bbc_dataset= r'C:\Users\A_A_A\Downloads\bbc-text.csv'

data_dict = get_data(bbc_dataset)
```

There are 2 functions now(edits)
I am not understanding why I am getting this error and how can I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: What does `read_in_csv` do? Please provide complete traceback and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just edited my question

Comment: The problem is that you iterate over the `reader` outside the with statement, and the file has been closed. Indent the `data = [row for row in reader]` to correct it.